# React native camera detecting face

Tags: javascript, react-native, camera, jsx

Does anyone know how to enable the React-native-camera face detection feature?

I've followed the guide on https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera such as importing and changing the line on package.json but still don't see anything happening to my camera when it is in front of a face

Answer (score 5):

react-native-camera doesn't do anything on its own to let you know that the face detection is working. It is up to you to do something with the data it provides.

This code snippet would show some text when a face is detected, for example:

```
constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    this.state = { isFaceDetected: false };
}

handleFaceDetected = faceArray => {
    this.setState(state => { ...state, isFaceDetected: true });
};

// ...

<RNCamera
    faceDetectionMode={RNCamera.Constants.FaceDetection.Mode.fast}
    onFacesDetected={this.handleFaceDetected}
/>
{this.state.isFaceDetected && (<Text>I saw a face</Text>)}
```

See the [react-native-camera face-detection documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md#face-detection-related-props) for more details.

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeCamera.RNCamera.Constants.FaceDetection.Mode.accurate')



Which is odd because my camera works just fine and i take photo's using the library the constants exists I just don't know why adding this line of code breaks it and it shouldn't.